# Android APK bigger than I expected

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, apk

I Build an APK using Android studio and its bigger than I expected. I attached a APK analyze report and it shows ***lib*** download file size is *56.6 MB*. can anyone suggest a way how can i reduce that lib size.

PS: And can someone explain me what is this ***lib*** means? becouse i did't use any libs other than dependency. and as i know those dependency included in ***classes.dex***

Thanks.

*Screen shot of the APK analyze :*

[image: Screen shot of the APK analyze]

[image: Screen shot of the build.gradle analyze]

Comment: You have a lib folder somewhere in the project with native (C/C++) libraries

Comment: Post your build.gradle, you may have used some other dependencies have used native libraries.

Comment: @NabinBhandari i update the post can you check. Thanks

Comment: do you need `vlc-android-sdk`?

Comment: @pskink yes i do i used it for the streaming. any suggestions?

Comment: so it comes with native `libvlc.so` libraries (i believe), thats why your apk is so big

Comment: @pskink so that means i have to deal with this size? is there any way to reduce the size ?

Comment: yes: use something else instead of `vlc-android-sdk`

Comment: @pskink thanks appreciate it!

Comment: btw what is the size after running [proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-code)?

Comment: it should be 3-5 MB but now its 66MB :(

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the dependency of vlc-android-sdk library which contains large native library (libvlc.so) and is included in the app, your apk size is large.

You can use splits or product flavors for different CPU architectures to include only necessary so files. Or you should use a different library.